# qt - Drag & Drop : Frame disappears

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, drag-and-drop, qt-designer

i'm about to create a drag and drop between two QGroubBox. each contains DragDropFrames, they are a subclass from QFrame, now i have the problem when i want to release the DragDropFrame from the GroupBox, it will disappear instantly

DragDropFrame:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        offset = ev->pos();
        if(!isReleaseFromParentWidget)
        {
            ReleaseFromParent(ev->pos());
        }
        isMouseDown = true;
    }
};

void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (ev->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
    }
}

void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    if (isMouseDown)
    {
        this->move(mapToParent(ev->pos() - offset));
    }
}

void ReleaseFromParent(QPoint point)
{
    oldParentWidget = parentWidget();
    setParent(parentWidget()->parentWidget());
    isReleaseFromParentWidget = true;
    this->move(mapToParent(offset));
}
```

when i call the ReleaseFromParent in the constructor from DragDropFrame and not somewhere else, everything works fine. but if dragdrop-action is not in process, every dragdropframe should have a groupbox as parent. anybody knows what i'm doing wrong? studyied it multiple times, and i think the logic is correct...

actually there isnt a full Drag and Drop functionallity i know, first i want to fix the problem that the movement works fine.

Comment: You talk about DnD, but where is `dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event)`, `dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)`, `dropEvent( QDropEvent* event)`, `QDrag`, etc.  Are you even following Qt's DnD framework (https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html)!?

Comment: actually i'm not so far in the implementation, because the basic movement doesnt work. first i want to fix that problem, before running into the next

Comment: You are approaching the problem in the wrong way.  You can't just move non-top-level widgets around like that as it messes with their parent layouts.  To DnD a widget from one parent to another, you must do it through the DnD framework: when the drag starts hide the widget, unhook it from it's parent layout; in the drop event of the target widget, add the dragged widget to the layout and make visible.

Comment: ok, so i'll have a look at the DnD-Framework. this seemed for me the most simple solution for the DnD